# How can I improve my Android Studio App Performance

Tags: java, android, android-studio

It just so happened, that I have created a class that has 1000+ lines.
After installing the app on the device, the application starts slowing the device really hard. Will rewriting this script to three different classes, approximately 300 lines each, solve my issue?

Comment: Not enough information to reason about slowness, might I suggest you run "Analyze > Inspect Code..." as a blind starter, look at the errors in the output.

Comment: Splitting class does not guarantee it will increase performance (make device perform normally) as latter is dependent on what you do in that class.

Comment: the amount of code you have is entirely irrelevant. you can create a forever loop with basically one line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your application uses the internet, it is possible, that the phone has a worse connection than your comp. Slower connection - you have to wait...
2. Read [responsive App](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) and [App performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) - VERY useful. you will know the name of your problem - bad responsiveness (not performance) - for better further searches

Answer (score 0):

No. The problem is not about how many lines are there, or how many classes, it is about the complexity of the algorithms and time each action takes.

- Try to use Threads or Handlers while possible to make the app more responsive.
- Also, don't do too much work inside `onCreate()`, `onResume()` methods to make the app load faster.

Comment: No, no. The app itself is not lagging, it causes the phone to slow down, lag and freeze

Answer (score 0):

Use [Systrace](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace). It is a great tool provided by Android community to help improve your app's performance by giving a detail info on what is happening in your app at a very low level.

It has many tutorials on how to use it available as official docs and on there YouTube Channel. But surely this software will do only good if you have some core concepts about the android operating system and how memory, threads etc are utilised. But you can also learn them along the way.